# getting time and date using html 5 date type

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am developing  android  application using Cordova and ionic framework ,in which i am using Html 5 `date` type to get the date its works fine.

Now i want to select the time along with the date (ie user can select the time )

is it possible with html5 `date` type ??

Here is my code

```
<input type="date" ng-model="meetingData.enddate" />

$scope.submitForm=function(meetingData){
  console.log(meetingData.enddate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="date">` does not have a feature to let pick time by user. You can set the **current time** as default through this whereas the date is selected by user.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var mins = new Date().getMinutes();

$scope.meetingData.enddate.setHours(hour);
$scope.meetingData.enddate.setMinutes(mins);
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CE2Jc2hnFVs8jdpdFMPq?p=preview)

Alternatively, You should look into **ui-timepicker** and **ui-datepicker**.